# How to securely store user's credit card information by using Drupal and Paypal?

Tags: payment-gateways

I am working with payment process in my drupal project. Also I have asked to use papal payment gateway (Paypal pro).

My outstanding requirement is to store user's credit card information for their future purchases.

What is the best way to implement this? I got with the suggestion to use [Commerce Card on File](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cardonfile) module. Will this work with Paypal also?

Comment: Let Paypal take care of that for you and then you don't have to. Less security worries.

Comment: Card on file does not work with paypal.

Comment: Here's the relevant feature request: https://www.drupal.org/node/1968592